# Get a specific element with xmllint

Tags: html, xml, linux, xml-parsing, xmllint

Consider the following HTML code as in file `example.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>
   <a href="/">
    <img src="/images/image.png"/>
   </a>
  </h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/" >link1<br /><span>content</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/folder" >link2<br /><span>more contend</span></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div><!-- .container -->
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="disc">
   <li><strong>no interest 1</strong></li>
   <li><strong>no interest 2</strong></li>
   <li><strong>no interest 3</strong></li>
   <li>keyword1: <strong>unkown_content</strong></li>
   <li>keyword2: <strong>unkown_content</strong></li>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- .container -->
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="disc">
   <li><a href="/folder1">not interested</a></li>
   <li><a href="/folder2">not interested</a></li>
   <li><a href="/folder3">not interested</a></li>
   <li>keyword1: <strong>unkown_content</strong></li>
   <li>keyword2: <strong>unkown_content</strong></li>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- .container -->
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to get the `unkown_content` after the second `keyword1`. I have
tried

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//li[text()='keyword1: ']" example.html 2>/dev/null
<li>keyword1: <strong>unkown_content</strong></li><li>keyword1: <strong>unkown_content</strong></li>
```

As you can see this returns both nodes with `keyword1`. How do I get the content of the last occurence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `xmllint --html --xpath "(//li[text()='keyword1: '])[last()]" example.html 2>/dev/null`.

Note the addition of `[last()]` - it points to the last occurrence of `//li[text()='keyword1: ']`. The braces around `//li[text()='keyword1: ']` are necessary, too, as `[last()]` is applied to a nodeset.

Comment: I did try the first one and it did not work. The second one, with the braces, did the trick. My final command is `xmllint --html --xpath "(//li[text()='keyword1: '])[last()]/strong/text()"`. This gets the content I need. Thanks.